# Is allowing blob: in Content-Security-Policy a risk?

Tags: xss, content-security-policy

Recently, I've set Content-Security-Policy headers for my web application. I've tried to be as strict as possible. What strikes me most is the fact that I had to allow `blob:` for `connect-src` and `img-src` due to a third-party component. (Both `connect-src` and `img-src`  are otherwise restricted to `self` and some hard-coded URLs.)

So, my question is: Is allowing `blob:` a general security risk in the sense that an attacker can in an injected script wrap any URL with `blob` and thus connect to any arbitrary resource?

Comment: Are you sure what this 3rd party component puts in that `Blob`? `blob:` could be an attack vector if attacker manage to create a `Blob` of their attack script. Difference with `data:` or `http:` is that this `Blob` must be created on the same origin than your website, which narrows the ways of building it (you cannot load a `Blob` from another origin using `blob:`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) represents file-like data in client's memory (it may also be backed up by a temporary file). That data can be loaded or saved using JavaScript commands, including loaded/saved to a [local file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) for persistence.

The URL is used for security reasons. That is, if the JavaScript trying to load or save a blob comes from `3rd-party.example.com`, then you can block that URL (as you've noticed) to prevent that script from accessing the file system.

If you trust the source of the JavaScript attempting to access blobs (a.k.a. local files), then authorizing them is safe. Of course, you should specifically add those third party domains to your policy:

```
Content-Security-Policy: connect-src 'self' '3rd-party.example.com', ...
```

The load & save features won't create an HTTP connection since it just load from & save to local files. This is *just* how the security is implemented in a browser.

Comment: I think if you want to add a blob, even from the same origin you have to use the keyword `blob:` to allow it. It's the protocol that matters here, not the website.

Comment: My example shows that you need to include the _other_ URL(s) if you want that JS to work as expected. The `blob` would also be necessary, indeed.

Comment: According to the spec (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src) the `connect-src` should never be used for `blob:` URLs but I guess the issue you're seeing is bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1264540 – I think adding `blob:` to `connect-src` should be safe because browser should never actually try to use it if spec is followed.

Comment: "*A blob represents data on the client's file system.*" - I don't think that's accurate, it does not allow specifying arbitrary paths like the `file:` scheme. Rather, a blob represents some file object *in memory* on the client system (possibly backed by a tmp file).